# how to get binary data with psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a column containing binary data. If I do `fetchone()` it is not giving me any data, instead I do `fetchall()` then get the result below. How can O get that binary data into a variable and then convert it into a base64 encoded string?

```
con = psycopg2.connect(config.DB_CONNECTION)                
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select image from user_tbl where mobile=%s",(str(jsond['mobb'][0]),))
print cur.fetchall()
```

```
[(read-only buffer for 0x038DA430, size 64041, offset 0 at 0x03AE61C0,)]
```

Answer (score 3):

`psycopg2` returns the binary data (probably stored in a `bytea` column in your table) in a `buffer` object in Python 2, or in a [`memoryview`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memory-views) in Python 3.

Both `buffer` and `memoryview` objects can be passed directly to a base64 string encoder, so this will encode the binary data in base 64:

```
import base64

rows = cur.fetchall()
binary_img = rows[0][0]
base64_img = base64.b64encode(binary_img)
```

In Python 2, if you want the binary data itself you can use `str()` or slice with `[:]` the `buffer` object. In Python 3 you can use the `tobytes()` method of the `memoryview` object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the buffer:

```
import base64

# your code here

data = base64.encode(curo[0].read())
```